# PySide how to set focus to new window and open it if not exists

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have started learning PySide from [example of Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/menusandtoolbars/) and try to code app which had two windows: "Schematic View" which is parent of "Layout View", each with menu bar. On start that should be only schematic window, and layout win should be started by switchtoLAYOUT in root of menubar.

My questions are:

1. How to make "switchtoLAYOUT" in root not to show the dropdown and still do action with only one instance of "Layout View" window ?
2. How to switch the focus between two windows ("switchtoLAYOUT" and "switchtoSCHEMATIC")?
3. Please inspect my code and suggest me something smart (that should not be hard).

The Code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class schematicWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(schematicWindow, self).__init__()
        self.defineSchWin()

    def defineSchWin(self):               
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction('&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        menubar.addMenu('&Edit')
        menubar.addMenu('&Passives')
        menubar.addMenu('&Descretes')
        menubar.addMenu('&IC\'s')
        swToLayMenu = menubar.addMenu('switchtoLAYOUT')
        swToLayAction = QtGui.QAction(self)
        swToLayAction.triggered.connect(self.layoutWindow)
        swToLayMenu.addAction(swToLayAction)    # open layoutWindow (if not exists) 
                                                # and set focus to layoutWindow 

        self.setGeometry(0, 300, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Schematic View')    
        self.show()

    def layoutWindow(self):
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

        window.statusBar()
        menubar = window.menuBar()
        switchtoSchMenu = menubar.addMenu('switchtoSCHEMATIC')
        window.setGeometry(100, 600, 500, 300)
        window.setWindowTitle('Layout View')
        window.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = schematicWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the layout window in your class, (you should put `self.layout_window = None` in the `__init__`). This function now checks if the window has been initialized, makes it if it has not been, makes sure it is visible, and then sets the new window to be the active window.  Something like: (this is not tested)

```
def layoutWindow(self):
    if self.layout_window is None:
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        self.layout_window = window
        window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

        window.statusBar()
        menubar = window.menuBar()
        switchtoSchMenu = menubar.addMenu('switchtoSCHEMATIC')
        window.setGeometry(100, 600, 500, 300)
        window.setWindowTitle('Layout View')
    else:
        window = self.layout_window

    window.show()
    window.activateWindow()
    window.raise() # just to be sure it's on top
```

([doc](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#activateWindow))

Comment: Obliged. Just have to change to .raise_() and it works. Can you help me how to click on "switchtoLAYOUT" without dropping down empty submenu?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Excuse me if I wasn't clear. If you click "File" it pulls down submenu with file options, but on "switchtoLAYOUT" there's no options, I want clicking on it to do an action instantly, not to pull down submenu.

Comment: @Alex add an action, not a menu http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmenubar.html#addAction-3